# How can I put a defined symbol as the integrand of NIntegrate, without using a functional form with a pattern test?

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

Something like this, I define an integrand (really big and hairy, simple below)

```
integrand = z (Exp[-x^2] + y - Cos[y]);
intfunc[z_] := NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];

intfunc[7.]
```

> NIntegrate::inumrexpr: Expression {2 z,-2 z,0} derived from integrand 2 z (E^-x^2+y-Cos[y]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.00350209,4.9965},{-9.29258,999.293}}. >>
>
> NIntegrate::mtdfb: Numerical integration with LevinRule failed. The integration continues with Method -> MultiDimensionalRule. >>
>
> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand z (E^-x^2+y-Cos[y]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,5},{-10,1000}}. >>

How can I do this without typing

```
intfunc[z_] := 
  NIntegrate[z (Exp[-x^2] + y - Cos[y]), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];
```

I'm aware that I could define the integrand as a function, via

```
ClearAll[integrand, intfunc]
integrand[z_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  z (Exp[-x^2] + y);
intfunc[z_] := 
  NIntegrate[integrand[z, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];
```

and then it will work,

```
intfunc[7.]
(* 3.5009*10^7 *)
```

But in the [actual integrand](http://pastebin.com/raw/EQeHPihG) I am doing, it seems much slower.  Possibly because the extra time to perform the test `?NumericQ`?  Is that the only way to do this?

Comment: Does this speed things up? `intfunc[z0_] := Block[{z = z0}, NIntegrate[ ... ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integrand` is a function and functions should be defined and called with explicit arguments. However, there is no need to use [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) with its arguments.

```
integrand[x_, y_, z_] = z (Exp[-x^2] + y - Cos[y]);
```

Since `intfunc` employs a numeric technique ([`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)) it should be defined with a `PatternTest`

```
intfunc[z_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[integrand[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];

intfunc[7.]

(*  3.5009*10^7  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I do it this way:

```
Block[{NIntegrate, x, y, z}, 
  intfunc[z_] = NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];
  ];

intfunc[7.]
(*  3.5009*10^7  *)
```

It's not a great general programmatic way to go, but in the middle of solving a problem, in which I have constructed an expression `integrand`, this is to me an easy way.  Blocking `x`, `y`, and `z` should be unnecessary (or else `integrand` could not depend on them), but sometimes I'm over-cautious.

*Update: Explanation*

The problem has three aspects: (1) to get the code for `integrand` to evaluate (2) before the pattern named `z` is evaluated (3) without `NIntegrate` evaluating, all during the evaluation of [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) or [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html).  I'll say something about the optional `?NumericQ` at the end.

There are various ways to address this. One way is to go around the problem entirely and use functions that have all parameters as arguments.  This is a better way to write a program.  This is the workaround the OP points out in the question (and repeated by [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104339/4999)).

But there are ways to address the problem directly.  [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), as in

```
Block[{NIntegrate}, code]
```

blocks the evaluation of `NIntegrate` during the execution of `code`.  Basically, the symbol is temporarily cleared of all its values and attributes.  So when the code

```
intfunc[z_] = NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];
```

is evaluated, all the arguments of `NIntegrate` are evaluated, and the definition becomes

```
intfunc[z_] = NIntegrate[<fn expr in x,y,z>, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];
```

where `<fn expr in x,y,z>` represents the value of `integrand`; and that is what `intfunc[z_]` is set to be equal to.

Another solution is substitution, which I skipped because I thought someone had already suggested it; e.g.,

```
intfunc[z0_] := NIntegrate[integrand /. z -> z0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];
```

The overhead from `?NumericQ` is negligible.  It could be quite desirable to use `intfunc[z0_?NumericQ]...` in the definitions above, especially if `intfunc[z]` is to be passed to another solver.

Why doesn't this work, with or without `NumericQ`?

```
intfunc[z_] := NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}];
```

Inspecting the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) of `intfunc` will help the explanation:

```
DownValues[intfunc]
(*  {HoldPattern[intfunc[z_]] :> NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}]}  *)
```

`SetDelayed` created a rewrite rule that replaces all instances of the symbol `z` in the literal, unevaluated expression `NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}]` by the argument to `intfunc`.  There are no instances of `z` in that code.  So both of these calls,

```
intfunc[7.]
intfunc[10.]
```

result in the same thing

```
NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -10, 1000}]
```

which is then evaluated.  At this point `integrand` is evaluated by `NIntegrate` and the symbolic `z` shows up.  In [@march's suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104333/how-can-i-put-a-defined-symbol-as-the-integrand-of-nintegrate-without-using-a-f/104343?noredirect=1#comment283189_104333)

```
intfunc[z0_] := Block[{z = z0}, NIntegrate[ ... ]]
```

the value of `z` would be equal to the value of the argument `z0`; if numeric, the evaluation of `NIntegrate` would proceed with no other difficulties except those posed by a pesky integrand.

As a final remark, the OP's actual expression for `integrand` is certainly pesky.  IMO the integrand itself is the only reason that `NIntegrate` is slow.

Comment: You are right that you only have to put `NIntegrate` in the `Block`, but I still don't understand how or why this works.  It does work though, without the pattern testing overhead of my original method.  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @JasonB I tried to explain in my update...HTH